# template toolkit remove , from the last entry

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have the following seciton on the template toolkit

```
names: [[% FOREACH name IN name %] '[% name %]', [% END %]]
```

which prints something like this :

names : ['name1','name2','name3',]

my question is there an option to tweak the above in order not to print the last comma i.e the result will be

names : ['name1','name2','name3']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside every `FOREACH` loop, you have access to the special `loop` variable - which is an instance of the [Template::Iterator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Iterator) class.

So you can write something like this:

```
names: [[% FOREACH name IN name %] '[% name %]'[% UNLESS loop.last %],[% END %] [% END %]]
```